# ¿Porque con el operador unario (*) no me imprime lo que hay dentro (como lo dice la teoria), pero sin el si?

Tags: c, punteros

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

# define DIM 10
char *copiar (char s[]);
void strcpy1 (char v[], char w[]);
int main()
{    
      char s[DIM]="hola";
      char *v;

      v=copiar(s);
      printf("%s \n",v);
      free (v);

      system("PAUSE");
      return 0;
}

char *copiar (char s[DIM])
{    
      char *q;
      q=malloc(DIM);
      strcpy1(q,s);
      printf("q :%s \n",q);
      return q;
}

void strcpy1 (char v[DIM], char w[DIM])
{    
      int i;
      for(i=0;i<DIM;i++)
       v[i]=w[i];
}
```

Comment: añade `q[DIM] = '\0';` antes de imprimir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preguntas por qué este `printf()` funciona (es decir, te imprime la cadena):

```
printf("%s \n", v);
```

pero este otro no (imprime algo raro, o rompe la ejecución):

```
printf("%s \n", *v);
```

ya que entiendes que lo que tienes que pasar como parámetro es *lo que hay* en la dirección apuntada por `v` y eso es lo que estarías pasando en el segundo caso y no en el primero.

La razón está en el formato `"%s"` de `printf()`, que no funciona como supones. De hecho funciona de forma diferente al resto de formatos como `"%d"`, `"%f"`,  `"%c"`, etc.

En el resto de formatos tendrías razón. Lo que hay que pasarles es un dato y no una dirección. Pero en el caso de `"%s"` es al revés. Este formato espera que lo que le pases sea una dirección de memoria. Lo que hace `printf()` internamente es acceder a esa dirección e imprimir el carácter que encuentre allí. Y después a la dirección siguiente para imprimirlo también. Y después a la siguiente, etc. deteniéndose sólo cuando encuentre un carácter nulo (que es el carácter cuyo código es `0` que también puede representarse por `'\0'`).

Así pues, cuando haces `printf("%s", v)` le estás pasando lo que espera (salvo por el hecho de que tu cadena quizás no tenga un nulo indicando su final, pues no lo has copiado como parte de tu función `strcpy1()`, y si te funciona es porque *casualmente* había un 0 en la dirección siguiente al que ocupa la `a` final).

Cuando haces `printf("%s", *v)`, en cambio, estás desreferenciando el puntero `v` para acceder a su primer carácter, y es ese primer carácter el que recibe `printf()`. En nuestro ejemplo, el primer carácter es una `h`, por lo que en realidad recibe el código ASCII de la `h` que es 104. Ya que `"%s"` espera una dirección de memoria, interpreta ese 104 como si lo fuera, y al tratar de acceder a esa dirección se producirá un resultado inesperado (casi siempre un *segmentation fault* por acceso a dirección protegida).

Otra cosa sería si hubieras puesto:

```
printf("%c", *v);
```

Fíjate que ahora la cadena de formato es `"%c"`. Aquí sí que se espera un carácter, y eso es lo que le estamos pasando, de modo que mostrará `h`. Claro que de esta forma no aparece la cadena completa sino sólo su primera letra. Y tiene todo el sentido porque `v` es un *puntero a carácter*, y no un *puntero a cadena* (si tal cosa existiera, que en realidad sería un `char **`).